# Transfer Learning for small datasets of structured data

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, transfer-learning

I am looking to implement machine learning for a problems that are built on small data sets related to approvals of expenses in a specific supply chain domain. Typically labelled data is unavailable

I was looking to build models in one data set that I have labelled data and then use that model developed in similar contexts- where the feature set is **very similar, but not identical**. The expectation is that this allows the starting point for recommendations and gather labelled data in the new context.

I understand this is the essence of Transfer Learning. Most of the examples I read in this domain speak of image data sets- any guidance how this can be leveraged in small data sets using standard tree-based classification algorithms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, we have decided to proceed with random forest models with the intuition that trees in the original model that have common features will form the starting point for decisions.

As we gain more labelled data in the new context, we will start replacing the original trees with new trees that comprise of (a)only new features and (b) combination of old and new features

This has worked to provide reasonable results in initial trials

Answer (score 1):

I can’t really speak to tree-based algos, I don’t know how to do transfer learning with them.  But, for deep learning models, the customary method for transfer learning is to load up a pretrained model, then retrain the last layer of the dataset using your new data, and then fine-tune the rest of the network.

If you don’t have much data to go on, you might look into creating synthetic data.

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I am avoiding deep learning models as the complexity is not justified in the simple scenarios that I face. While I understand deep-learning models create abstraction in the initial layers, is there an equivalent here for abstraction here? How would I handle the incremental new features and missing features

Answer (score 1):

raghu, I believe you are looking for a kernel method when you are saying abstraction layer in deep learning. There are several ML algorithms that support kernel functions. With kernel functions, you might be able to do it; but using kernel functions might be more complex than solving your original problem. I would lean toward Tdoggo's suggestion of using Decision Tree.

Sorry, I want to add a comment, but they won't allow me, so I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok with tree-based algos you can do just what you said: train the tree on one dataset and apply it to another similar dataset.  All you would need to do is change the terms/nodes on the second tree.

For instance, let’s say you have a decision tree trained for filtering expenses for a construction company.  You will outright deny any reimbursements for workboots, because workers should provide those themselves.

You want to use the trained tree on your accounting firm, and so instead of workboots, you change that term to laptops, because accountants should be buying their own.

Does that make sense, and is that helpful to you?